# Changing order of shopping cart totals in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I am having a requirement that I have to change the order of totals in a shopping cart in Magento. My requirement is shipping charge should display before Tax. Currently it is displaying as Subtotal-Tax-shipping charge-Grand Total and I need as Subtotal-shipping charge-Tax-Grand total.
Can anyone help me from where I can edit this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure it in the Magento backend itself. Go to **System->Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order**.Set the sorting order as you wish.

Comment: Can you please suggest what I can do, to reflect the same changes in order confirmation email and view order page in my account section.

Comment: download/install a new fresh magento in your local machine and see the order again from the path provided by @ROHIT S

Comment: Take a look at  app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Sales/Order/Tax.php.You probably need to override this core class to acieve it.

Comment: I cannot see this setting under Magento ver. 1.9.2.4, may I know which version you were using.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any code.

Just configure it from admin panel: Go to System->Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order.Set the sorting order as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you can change order in admin site
 **Admin -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order**

but can't change **Order Total Excl. Tax** and  **Order Total Incl. Tax**
if you won't change it order to **Order Total Incl. Tax** and   **Order Total Excl. Tax** please overide **Magento_Tax** module **web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html**  same as

```
<tr class="grand totals excl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grand totals incl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: inclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': inclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```