# Change order of Order Details in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento checkout page and in the last step I want order details as

[image]

but presently i am getting Details in order as follows [image]

How can I change order of Details?

Comment: This question has been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14577277/3563981

Comment: Thanks for solution but it is not working for me as I am using my module for Specific Shipping method.So when I change its order from admin,Specific shipping method is not coming down.